# Expand an Array of structs to a larger size dynamically

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, int

I have a dilemma where I have a struct which contains an array of structs...

```
typedef struct Container{
    struct Inner *F;
    int length;
} Memo;

typedef struct Inner{
    int *digits;
    int length;
} Inner;
```

Well I call this function:

```
int expandContainer(Container *container, int n)
```

So basically when I pass this 'container' into 'expandContainer' I initialize a new Inner array of some size and then malloc it and I want to make the inner that is passed in through the function via container to be "expanded" and updated and the temporary Inner array to be free'd upon exit from the function.

Just to be clear the Inner being passed into the function is not be destroyed in anyway because it is going to be used elsewhere it only needs to be literally "expanded" to hold more data than it was originally capable of. Here is what I have...

```
int arrayLength, i;

//Get new array length
if(((memo->length * 2) + 1) > (n * 2 + 1))
    arrayLength = ((memo->length * 2) + 1);
else
    arrayLength = (n * 2 + 1);

//Create new Array
Inner *biggerArray;

//Malloc new array of Inner Structs
biggerArray = malloc(sizeof(Inner) * arrayLength);

    //Check for errors
    if(biggerArray == NULL)
        panic("ERROR: out of memory in expandContainer()\n");

//Copy data from container->F into biggerArray
for(i=0; i<container->length; i++)
    biggerArray[i] = container->F[i];

//Initialize remaining data in biggerArray
for(i=container->length; i<arrayLength; i++)
    {
        biggerArray[i].digits = NULL;
        biggerArray[i].length = 0;
    }

//Free the old array
for(i=0; i<arrayLength; i++)
    //!!!!THIS DOESN'T WORK!!!!!
    &(memo->F[i]) = &biggerArray[i];

//free the biggerArray created in the function
free(biggerArray);

//update the length of memo
memo->length = arrayLength;

printf("-> Expanded Container capacity to %d.\n", arrayLength);

return arrayLength;
```

Not sure if I am implementing correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For the expansion itself, you can use `realloc`. It does exactly what you need. Allocate a new (bigger) area, copy the data and free the old one.

If you want to wrap it with a function like expandContainer(). It must get the pointer by reference:

```
int expandContainer(Container **container, int n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using realloc instead of malloc and its always a good idea to initialize newly allocated pointers and variables to NULL ( or 0)
You may use memcpy to copy the old array to new array (in case you want to stick to malloc or better calloc)

Answer (score 0):

Is this useful?

```
//Free the old array
free(memo->F);
// you don't free the biggerArray, instead
memo->F = biggerArray;
//update the length of memo
memo->length = arrayLength;
```